# uasort() not performing all possible comparisons

Tags: php, sorting

I have this code:

```
$ids = array(13952979,13952983,13952997,13952999,13953001,13953009,13953011,13953013);
uasort($ids, function($a, $b){
  echo $a . ',' . $b . "<br>";
});
```

This ends up echoing:

```
13952999,13952983
13953013,13952999
13952999,13952997
13953011,13952999
13952999,13952979
13953009,13952999
13953001,13952999
13952997,13952979
13952983,13952997
13953013,13953001
13953009,13953013
13953011,13953013
13953009,13953011
```

Notice that the combination `13952979,13952983` - or its reverse - is not one of the comparisons. This causes the sort to only sort partially.

Why is it not performing a comparison between `13952979` and `13952983`? How can I make it so that it performs all possible comparisons?

Comment: If `a < b` and `b < c`, it doesn't need to compare `a` and `c` directly to know that `a < c`.

Comment: Sorting algorithms are generally designed to minimize the number of comparisons, so they execute in O(n log n) time instead of O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to perform all possible comparisons to sort an array. It performed the comparisons `13952997,13952979` and `13952983,13952997`. From these, it can infer the result of `13952979,13952983`, so it doesn't need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sorting, at least not with the current code. There is no comparison done in you function, thus `PHP` uses the default return value, which is equal to 0 (all items are equal), resulting in the incorrect behaviour you noticed.

This should behave better:

```
uasort($ids, function($a, $b){
    echo $a . ',' . $b . "<br>";
    return $a - $b; // or $b - $a, depending on the sort order you need
});
```